# Run multiple python files simultaneously and terminate all when one has finished

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to run multiple python files simultaneously, but when one finishes, kill all of the rest. I only need to know the output of the python file that finishes first. After much trial and error, I have decided to use a bash file (I am running Ubuntu) to start all of the files simultaneously, however, I cannot stop all of them once the first one is done.Please help, thanks!!! I have tried many answers I have found online with no success. I have even written a python file to kill other python files which works when started from the terminal but not when called from the bash file or another python file. I feel like I am over complicating the problem. Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Assuming I take in a variable named pass and I pass that to each file here are the commands I want to run in parallel:

```
 read pass
 python3 1.py "$pass"
 python3 2.py "$pass"
 python3 3.py "$pass"
 python3 4.py "$pass"
 python3 5.py "$pass"
 python3 6.py "$pass"
 python3 7.py "$pass"
 python3 8.py "$pass"
 python3 9.py "$pass"
```

Comment: Why would you need to launch multiple processes but only take the output of the first to finish? This doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Ideally I would utilize multiple processes or threads in C or Java, but I need to use python for other reasons and so each file is given the same input but it is trying operations on the same data. There is only one answer so only one of the files should work

Comment: can't you use forking? you can do all the processes you need, and when a process ends you can exit all the others manually, but I can't really think why you want to exit other processes if it is still working

Comment: So all of the processes are doing the same thing and probably finish within less than a second of each other. Depending on how many processes you launch, they may be competing for resources.

Comment: Yes they are all doing the same thing, but only one file will actually finish. All of the others will continue to look for an answer that is not there.

Comment: @MobrineHayde I am sorry, I am relatively new to python, what do you mean by forking, and I would like the file that returns the output to kill the other files automatically so that I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: I'm failing to see the advantage of running more than one here...

Comment: Please explain a bit more on `"
I need to run multiple python files simultaneously, but when one finishes, kill all of the rest."`

Comment: Python can be multithreaded and even multicore! You do not need to run multiple Python files, only one. Look into the `multiprocessing` library.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Really? Everyone I've talked to said that it wasn't and to pick a different language. Maybe I misunderstood them.

Comment: It's true that the Python interpreter itself can only run one thread of Python code at a time, but that doesn't mean the C libraries that it can make calls to have the same restriciton ;)

Comment: Wait, I have looked into this but I didn't find a way to use it when I am giving the same file the same input. I only found how to give the same file different input or a different file the same input.

Comment: Perhaps you can post some code for us to look at, and we can help you parallelize it using `multiprocessing`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. @Kos, thank you maybe later I have to go. Thank you everyone

Comment: It is a design problem, this problem can be addressed with command pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little example of how you can start multible python scripts in parallel. After the first script print the output result, all other where be killed.

python script

```
import sys
import time
seconds = sys.argv[1]
time.sleep(int(seconds))
print("runner sleep {} seconds.".format(seconds))
```

bash script

```
start() {                   # function for starting python scripts
    echo "start $@"         # print which runner is started
    "$@" &                  # start python script in background
    pids+=("$!")            # save pids in array
}

start ./runner.py 5         # start python scripts
start ./runner.py 7
start ./runner.py 1
start ./runner.py 2
start ./runner.py 3
start ./runner.py 9
start ./runner.py 8
start ./runner.py 3
start ./runner.py 4
start ./runner.py 7

wait -n "${pids[@]}"           # wait for first finished process
kill "${pids[@]}" 2>/dev/null  # kill all/other process
```

output

```
start ./runner.py 5
start ./runner.py 7
start ./runner.py 1
start ./runner.py 2
start ./runner.py 3
start ./runner.py 9
start ./runner.py 8
start ./runner.py 3
start ./runner.py 4
start ./runner.py 7
runner sleep 1 seconds.
```

Comment: You could get rid of the `pids` array by running `wait -n` without any PIDs to wait for all children, and `pkill -P "$$"` to kill all of the shell's children.

Comment: @UtLox I am getting this error on line 6: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") For me, line 6 is this: pids+=("$!")

Comment: Your script starts with "#!/bin/sh" - correct? Use "#!/bin/bash" and it will be run!

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer**

Thank you for your inputs. In the light of those, I would suggest you use:

```
parallel --dry-run -k --halt now,success=1 python3 {}.py "$pass" ::: {1..9}
```

**Sample Output**

```
python3 1.py "$pass"
python3 2.py "$pass"
python3 3.py "$pass"
python3 4.py "$pass"
python3 5.py "$pass"
python3 6.py "$pass"
python3 7.py "$pass"
python3 8.py "$pass"
python3 9.py "$pass"
```

If that looks correct, you can remove `--dry-run` and `-k` and simply run:

```
parallel --halt now,success=1 python3 {}.py "$pass" ::: {1..9}
```

**Original Answer**

I think you can leverage **GNU Parallel** for this, specifically its *halt* policy. So, as an example, start 10 jobs, that sleep 10, 20, 30, 40... 100 seconds each and kill the others as soon as any one succeeds:

```
parallel --halt now,success=1 sleep {} ::: $(seq 10 10 100)
parallel: This job succeeded:
sleep 10
```

If you add `-k` and `--dry-run` after `parallel`, you will see that it starts the following jobs:

```
parallel -k --dry-run --halt now,success=1 sleep {} ::: $(seq 10 10 100)

sleep 10
sleep 20
sleep 30
sleep 40
sleep 50
sleep 60
sleep 70
sleep 80
sleep 90
sleep 100
```

---

Another example which kills outstanding jobs once 20% of the jobs have succeeded:

```
parallel --halt now,success=20% sleep {} ::: $(seq 10 10 100)
parallel: This job succeeded:
sleep 10
parallel: This job succeeded:
sleep 20
```

Comment: I see you have the same task, sleep, but you pass different variables to it: 10, 10, 100. How would I use this if I have the same input but different files?

Comment: Click `edit` under your question and add a list of the commands you want to run in parallel and I'll update my answer to show how.

Comment: I have updated my answer - please have another look.