How to get string output from multiple background child process in zsh
I am having a script which I run in zsh. Upon invoking the script, it runs the main_process() function. The main_process requires ${hash_from_evaluator} for rest of its operation, however calculating this value takes time.
To speed things up, I first invoke 5 _evaluator() as sub-processes in the background, which can run independently and parallel, to find out some value of ${hash_from_evaluator}.
main_process() can operate with any value of $hash_from_evaluator as long as it matches a given regex. Any sub-process which first returns this value can be taken, and then remaining sub-processes must then be killed.
I request for your kind help please. I am able to launch the sub-processes, however, unable to monitor if any one of them has returned the value, then use the value and kill rest sub-processes. How do I do this in zsh?
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
zmodload zsh/system


_evaluator(){
  printf "launched subprocess $1 with PID $sysparams[pid]"
  
  while ! [[ ${hash_from_evaluator} =~ ${input_regex} ]]; do
    hash_from_evaluator="custom commands to maniuplace some data and get some hash as result"
  done
  
  return_value="subprocess $1 calculated ${hash_from_evaluator}"
  echo ${return_value}
}


main_process(){
  local input_regex="^abc123"
  local hash_from_evaluator=""

  for i in {1..5}; do
    echo "starting subprocess $i"
    _evaluator $i &
    pids[$i]=$!
  done

  # Requesting for yout kind help here please
  # wait for any one of the 5 subprocesses to give back $return_value.
  # assign this $return_value to hash_from_evaluator.
  # kill other 4 child processes.

  .... rest of the script consumes any valid ${hash_from_evaluator} in match with $input_regex
}


main_process "$@"



Crossposted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1523106/158442

looks like they removed the crosspost !

Simple with GNU Parallel if that's an option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304905/2836621

For getting the output of the subprocesses you'll need something like a FIFO file. Do the evaluators only output a single and small line?

No. It is long string of data along with PIK signature produced with every iteration of while loop. Fortunately it is plain text.

If it's too long for simultaneous writes to be atomic then you'll need an output file per process.

Thanks @Fravadona. Unfortunately it is not preferred in my situation to use a file. The contents are comparatively sensitive. Any other way to directly communicate with the parent process to return result?

@BhaveshDiwan Well, I guess you could use something like IPC, but FIFO files are a lot easier to handle, and safer; you just have to create the named pipe(s) in a temp dir with the right ACLs.

Here's what you could do.
At the start of the script you create a temporary directory, a fifo file (to use as "FD3"), a locking mechanism and a trap to clean everything up:
tempdir=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1
trap 'rm -rf "$tempdir"' EXIT

mkfifo -m 600 "$tempdir/fifo" || exit 1
exec 3<>"$tempdir/fifo"

lockex() { ln -s _ "$tempdir/lock" 2> /dev/null; }

then in _evaluator you output your result to "FD3", but only when the exclusive lock was successful; that way, only the first _evaluator to complete will be able to do it:
_evaluator() {
    # ...
    lockex && printf '%s\0' "$return_value" >&3
}

and in main_process you wait by reading from "FD3":
main_process() {
    # ...
    for i in {1..5}; do
        _evaluator "$i" &
        pids[i]=${!}
    done

    IFS='' read -u 3 -r -d $'\0' hash_from_evaluator
    kill "${pids[@]}"

    # ... rest of the script that consumes the first $hash_from_evaluator
}

note: I replaced pids[$i]=$! with pids[$i]=${!}, as the former doesn't work anymore with modern versions of zsh

Thanks @Fravadona
I will test the approach you've proposed and share feedback whenever I'm touching the code again; hopefully soon!
